# How to compute/estimate the probability of the mean value of a number of x results of a classification NN?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, mean, softmax

I use a neural network to classify the sentiment of some news articles per day, regarding a specific topic. Possible results are $[1,2,3,4,5]$ (1=very negative, ..., 5 = very positive). Using one article as input the network gives me as output, a number 1-5, describing the sentiment and the corresponding probability (a softmax probability), e.g. sentiment = 2, probability = 0.65.

I am interested in assigning a probability (or more precisely an estimation of the probability) to the
mean sentiment of today's articles.

It has been suggested to me (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025614/how-to-compute-estimate-the-probability-of-the-mean-value-of-x-results-if-each/4025797#4025797) that  a possible a way to assign a probability to this mean (the average of the articles sentiments) by taking into account the softmax probabilities assigned to each article would be:

Assuming that I have n articles, $X_1,...,X_n$ with mean sentiment $\bar X$. A probability that takes into account the softmax probabilities is:

$$\sum_{x_i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\\bar x_i=\bar X}P(X_1=x_1)*P(X_2=x_2)*...*P(X_n=x_n)$$

I understand that this approach is correct from a statistics point of view, yet taking into the nature of the problem, i'm not sure that the probabilities $P(X_1=x_1)*P(X_2=x_2)*...*P(X_n=x_n)$ can be considered independent (since the articles refer to the same topic and obviously the content of one article is correlated with the content of the others). I have been given a guideline to consider all the distributions as normal.

Is there a way to compute the conditional probabilities and use this approach?
Any other suggestion to estimate the probability of the mean?